# React.js: Is there a simpler way of defining Form Input element as a best practice ? Without using another library or extension

Tags: reactjs

After having gone thru a few docs & books on React, I understand that, for an Html Form input element that could be defined as:

```
<form>
  <label>
    Name:
    <input type="text" name="name" />
  </label>
</form>
```

the recommended best practice in React is to use the "Controlled component" approach with an equivalent code like the following [Sample from React Forms doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components):

```
class NameForm extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {value: ''};
      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    } //constructor

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({value: event.target.value}); 
    } // handleChange

    render() {
        return (
          <form>
            <label>
              Name:
              <input 
                type="text" 
                value={this.state.value} 
                onChange={this.handleChange} 
              />
            </label>
      </form>
      );
    }  //render

} // class
```

Is there a simpler alternative in React itself (without adding additional libraries or extensions) ?  Please excuse, if I missed something basic.

Comment: That's the simplest it will get with vanilla react.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the simplest approach. It's also correct. 
One way to further simplify is to give the `onChange` an anonymous arrow function.

```
  <form>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input 
            type="text" 
            value={this.state.value} 
            onChange={e => this.setState({ value: e.target.value })} 
          />
        </label>
  </form>
```

But no advantage here really. Your approach makes it more readable.

But there is a more simple way to initialize state.

It's like this:

```
class NameForm extends React.Component {

    state = { value: "" }
    ....
}
```

And if you make class methods arrow functions you don't have to bind them:

`handleChange = (event) => { .... }`